# Difference between $(document).on and ($ document).on in CoffeeScript?

Tags: javascript, jquery, coffeescript, domdocument

My friend is using `($ document).on` in his CoffeeScript code. Does this differ from the usual `$(document).on` and if so, in what way?

Comment: It's just a parenthesized function call; in other words it's the CoffeeScript equivalent of `($(document)).on`

Comment: @Pointy so all this does is increase the size of the file?

Comment: I'm not a CoffeeScript person but it may be necessary to make the `.` expression work properly. In other words, `$ document.on` might be interpreted incorrectly without the extra `()`. (That, by the way, would be in the list of reasons that I'm not a CoffeeScript person :)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

In CoffeeScript, calling a function **with arguments** does not requires parentheses.

For example:

```
console.log("Hello") // Hello
console.log "Hello"  // Hello
```

So, consider that these are equivalent:

```
$document = $(document)
$document = $ document
$document = ($ document)
```

However, parentheses are, under certain circumstances, necessary to disambiguate meaning.

For example, you want the `on` function to be called on the return of the `$()` function:

```
$(document).on() // on function called on the return of $() function
```

But this would not work as intended:

```
$ document.on() // $() function called with document.on() return!
```

So, to enforce that the `on` function is called on the result of the `$()` function, we add parentheses:

```
($ document).on() // on function called on the return of $() function
```

**Be aware** that, according to the [CoffeeScript style guide](https://github.com/polarmobile/coffeescript-style-guide#functions),

> The function grouping style is not recommended.

So do recommend your friend to stop using it :)